# Calling an ootb workflow automatically from custom workflow aem 6.5.13

Tags: workflow, aem

Recently I have updated to 6.5.13 SP for aem. There is a custom workflow for page deactivation, which has the following steps:
Start-->lock payload--> create version-->Approval requested to content-administrator--> Approval granted by content administrator-->Deactivate Page/Asset-->Unlock Payload--> Sent Email to content author.
After upgrading to SP 13 , I noticed a difference in the workflow. After the unlock payload step, it is automatically calling and starting the OOTB workflow (request for deactivation).
Can anyone help me here. I have verified that none of the processes calls the OOTB workflow, and it was perfectly fine before installing service pack.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an additional launcher active maybe that is called by that event? Maybe the default workflow has been reactivated with the update.